# Can I open my own socket on receiving a silent remote notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, nsstream

Am I allowed to open my own socket to download new data on receiving a silent remote notification on iOS?

Comment: It might be possible to register yourself for background operation using an `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Yeah sure but can I open a socket and use the CFStreaming API to download data over it?

Comment: Not if your application is still in the background.

Comment: Hmm I found that out. Thanks for your help though.